# PercTable {DescTools} - prevent output text wrapping

Tags: export-to-csv, desctools

My goal is to export PercTable output in a clean / HTML like format as JPG or CSV import into a presentation.

I get the "raw" table I want with this code:

```
    Library(DescTable)
    PercTable(syn_gender ~ recommend, data=dfXtab, rfrq="010", expected=TRUE)
```

It outputs as shown in graphic.
[Screen snapshot for space saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4hOX.png)

How can I **export** this output without the table wrapping the last 2 column?

Thank you - newbie.

Answer (score 0):

The `PercTable` print routine uses the console width (`getOption("width")`) to define the table breaks. So the first solution is to simply enlarge the console width and print again.

Another option for output if you're on Windows is to use the Office export (`package RDCOMClient` needed):

```
library(DescTools)
tt <- PercTable(table(d.pizza$operator, 
                      cut(d.pizza$temperature, breaks=6)))

wrd <- GetNewWrd()
ToWrd(tt$ftab)
```

would yield:

[image: WordTable]